# Why does a non-monotonic ROC curve plotting error occur when using list of roc for ggrow?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, random-forest, roc

I am traing a 10 fold crossvalidated random forest in R.  I have provided the list of roc objects is [here for download][https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ZYs1gMzPr64lV7WQmVOu1zt0YSVak9cr] , it is the 'my_roclist.rds' file.  The code to make the plot at the bottom is here:

```
library(pROC)
library(ggplot2)

# load the my_roclist.rds file I've provided in the google drive
hochgerner.roc.list <- loadRDS("my_roclist.rds")
        
# plotting
jpeg('hochgerner2018_earlysig_roc.jpeg', width = 600, height=600)
ggroc(hochgerner.roc.list,  alpha = 1,
      colour = "red", linetype = 'solid',
      size = 4, legacy.axes = TRUE) + 
  theme_classic() + 
  ggtitle("Hochgerner et al., (2018) ROC") + 
  xlab("FPR") + ylab("TPR") + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0, xend = 1, y = 0, yend = 1), linewidth = 2,
               color="darkgrey", linetype="dashed") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 20, face = "bold", 
                                  hjust = 0.5),
        axis.text=element_text(size=20, face = "bold", colour="black"),
        axis.title =element_text(size=20, face = "bold", 
                                 colour="black"),
        panel.border = element_rect(color = "black",
                                    fill = NA,
                                    linewidth = 2),
        plot.margin = margin(t = 10, r = 10, b = 10, l = 10) ) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0)), 
                     breaks = c(0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0)),  
                       breaks = c(0.25,0.5,0.75,1))
dev.off()
```

I am using the [pROC package][https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pROC/pROC.pdf] to generate plots from a random forest model with cross validation.  Each fold is executed inside a for loop and an ROC for that curve computed then added to a list of ROC objects.  At the end of the training the forests are combined.  I plot the fold specific ROCs with [ggroc][https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pROC/versions/1.18.4/topics/ggroc.roc] by providing it a list of the roc objects.  ggroc() should then plot a curve for each fold's roc, [tutorial here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66505014/how-to-add-auc-to-a-multiple-roc-graph-with-procs-ggroc). This issue appears to be specific to the data I am feeding it so I cannot reproduce the plot.  Why is the ROC non-monotonic?  That should be impossible, and the code I am using to produce the model is very straight forward.  What could I be doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: You (correctly) reported this problem bug: https://github.com/xrobin/pROC/issues/121
What is your question here?

Comment: The github didn't seem to be getting regular responses to some issues so I figured I would try here as well just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authors of the pROC package answered the question on their github, and have provided a fix.  The issue is here: https://github.com/xrobin/pROC/issues/121